# SharePoint 2013 Batch update list items C# SSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml, ssom, batch

I am trying to use batch update for one of the list in SP2013 site. I am trying to run a simple batch request as follows.

```
        using (var spSite = new SPSite(siteName))
        using (var spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
        {

            var clientList = spWeb.Lists["Clients"];


            string batchFormat = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
            "<ows:Batch OnError=\"Return\">"
            +"<Method ID=\"{0}\">" +
             "<SetList>{1}</SetList>" +
             "<SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Save</SetVar>" +
             "<SetVar Name=\"ID\">{2}</SetVar>" +
             "<SetVar Name=\"InstitutionType\">{3}</SetVar>" +
            "</Method>"+"</ows:Batch>", 1, clientList.ID,833, "None");

            spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            spWeb.ProcessBatchData(batchFormat);

        }
```

And I am getting response of spWeb.ProcessBatchData(batchFormat); as

```
<Results><Result ID="1" Code="0">
</Result>
</Results>
```

Can anyone please suggest me what is the correct way to perform batch updates. It runs but nothing is updated in list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you have set ID 833, so it will only update the item which has ID 833.

Modify your code as below:

```
using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteName))
{
    using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        StringBuilder methodBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string batch = string.Empty;
        string batchFormat = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
        "<Batch OnError=\"Return\">{0}</Batch>";

        string methodFormat = "<Method ID=\"{0}\">" +
        "<SetList>{1}</SetList>" +
        "<SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Save</SetVar>" +
        "<SetVar Name=\"ID\">{2}</SetVar>" +
        "<SetVar Name=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#InstitutionType\">{3}</SetVar>" +
        "</Method>";

        SPList list = spWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Clients");
        if(list!=null)
        {
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<View/>";
            SPListItemCollection listItem = list.GetItems(query);

            foreach (SPListItem item in listItem)
            {
                methodBuilder.AppendFormat(methodFormat, item.ID, list.ID, item.ID, "None");
            }

            batch = string.Format(batchFormat, methodBuilder.ToString());

            // Process the batch of commands.
            string batchReturn = spWeb.ProcessBatchData(batch);
            spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to update for single item only, although I will modify it for large number of items but for now I am concerned about the fact that it is not working for single item and will it work for large number of items.

Comment: hmm if you are updating  a single item why use batch ? :) 
normally i use `list.GetItemById(1)`  and then update the metadata. Batch should be used for bulk updates !

Comment: Am I missing something in syntax or any other thing, This single item should have been updated, but nothing is updated for it.

Comment: I used it for multiple items, but then it didn't worked for multiple items. Then I tried to do some POC kind of stuff and modified it to update only single item, even ID is hardcoded here. But still it didn't worked.

Comment: not 100% sure about this, but your code uses `<ows:Batch` whereas I am using `<Batch` that could be the difference. But again not sure about that, otherwise your code looks good. I have referenced this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms437562.aspx

Comment: Hi Gautham, I think I was missing \"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#ColumnName\" in SetVar Name property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.processbatchdata.aspx

Comment: It worked after this update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It will surely help me for bulk updates.

Comment: Awesome, am updating the answer for future references